# CSS image background position

Tags: css, background

This is my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/pbgLc/

I need the background image (with url) to be placed at the top left position of the image, and want the text to be moved next to the background image.

As you've probably noticed I'm using two backgrounds, so its probably not possible to use just one div, right?

Have you guys any solutions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but you can have 2 background elements at the same time, as long as they don't conflict each other. http://jsfiddle.net/pbgLc/5/

Comment: Um, is it just me or this background not appearing? `background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32x32/text_list_bullets.png') no-repeat;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help a little? [CSS background-position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)
If you want the image and the text next to each other, why don't you put them litterly next to each other?
2 divs inside 1 div

Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I cant but them together into one div, because there will be 2 background attributes.

Comment: Can't you give the container-div the css-styling for the borders, the left-inner-div the logo and the right-inner-div the text? You'd have to use 3 ID's/classes